# Как связать клиентскую и серверную часть в node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, модули

#### Ситуация:

Допустим у меня есть **node.js** файл с именем `server.js` который запускает **express** сервер по адресу `127.0.0.1:3000`. Так же у меня есть файл `index.html` в котором есть обычная **html-страница** с `‹input id="nickname"›`. И есть **javascript** файл `client.js` который считывает значение текстового поля с html-страницы.

#### Вопрос:

Как мне связать клиентскую и серверную часть что бы `client.js` считывал значение текстового поля с `index.html` и передавал это значение в `server.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запускаете ваш сервер с server.js, далее в этом файле отдаете содержимое index.html клиенту, который слушает 3000 порт (на уровне web-сервера проксируем запросы с 80 или 443 на 3000 порт).

Связка index.html и client.js реализуется традиционно для web'а (например, пишем client.js в HEAD-часть и вешаем там обработчик).

Comment: А как еще сюда базу данных mongodb прикрепить?

Comment: как любую другую базу данных. в файле server.js прописываете установку соединения, после чего там же делаете запросы к БД. другой вопрос, зачем вам mongodb? ее целесообразнее ставить как минимум, когда есть серверный кластер, а когда единичный сервер с относительно небольшой нагрузкой, то лучше используйте mysql.